# is it possible to invoke one VS code extension to another?

Tags: javascript, html, axios, vscode-extensions, git-pull

Is it possible to invoke extension with different functionality in already created extension for some other task?like I have created extension which working on some other task but now in same I want to add git pull part is it possible to do?

I have tried to call api of pull request in backend then trying to call that using axios